# TFS 2015 and Azure VMs File Copy

Tags: azure, deployment, tfs

In TFS I selected Azure VMs File Copy:

My machine is classic and I created classic storage account. I set up the connection using username and password, not management certificate.
[image]

The storage account and cloud service I had to populate myself, because they did not appear in the drop-down menu (so possibly something is wrong already at this stage).
In the Cloud Service I entered MyMachine.cloudapp.net.

The task starts, it seems to login successfully, but throws:

> Unable to find type [Hyak.Common.CloudException]

Log:

> 2017-11-24T14:21:28.80333Z Add-AzureAccount -Credential $psCredential
> 2017-11-24T14:21:35.866333Z Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionId -Default
> 2017-11-24T14:21:35.882333Z Set-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionId yy -CurrentStorageAccountName yyy
> 2017-11-24T14:21:35.898333Z ##[debug]Starting Azure File Copy Task
> 2017-11-24T14:21:35.898333Z ##[debug]connectedServiceNameSelector = ConnectedServiceName
> 2017-11-24T14:21:35.898333Z [debug]connectedServiceName = yyyyyy
> (..) 
> 2017-11-24T14:21:35.991333Z ##[debug]Loading AzureUtilityLTE9.8.ps1
> 2017-11-24T14:21:36.007333Z ##[debug]Connection type used is
> UsernamePassword
> 2017-11-24T14:21:36.022333Z ##[debug]Azure
> CallRetrieving storage key for the storage account:
> mystorageaccount
>
> 2017-11-24T14:21:38.924333Z ##[error]Unable to find type
> [Hyak.Common.CloudException].

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need to manually type the storage account, it will auto appear in the drop list. You just need to specify a **pre-existing** classic storage account. It is also used as an intermediary for copying files to Azure VMs.

> **Classic Storage Account**
>
> Required if you select Azure Classic for the Azure Connection Type
>   parameter. **The name of an existing storage account within the Azure
>   subscription.**

According to your  log, the issue may related to the storage account setting. Double check this configuration under your Azure subscription.

Also suggest you go through [this documentation](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/AzureFileCopy/README.md) to get more info of the Azure File Copy task. Such as make sure  the machine should configured to allow WinRM connections.

Comment: Thank you, Patrick, I am using an existing storage account. As per documentation: "If you use a Credentials-based 'Azure' endpoint we don't automatically populate the Storage & Resource Group/Cloud Service fields for you yet." So at least this behaviour seems correct.

Comment: The machine accepts Powershell remoting without issues so WinRM should be properly configured as well

Comment: @grisha  Have you tried to check if you could  copy files to Azure VM by using AzCopy command-line or not? The TFS Azure copy task is actually uses **AzCopy**, the command-line utility built for fast copying of data from and into Azure storage accounts. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy#file-upload